# Finding Angle Measures

Tags: geometry

An A-frame house is 40 feet high and 30 feet wide. Find the measure of the angle that the roof makes with the floor. Round to the nearest degree.

Comment: It is just a triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that the front face is an isosceles triangle, with base $30$ and height $40$.

Draw that triangle. Let $A$ and $B$ be the two ends of the base, and let $C$ be the remaining vertex. Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$, meeting $AB$ at $M$.

Let $\theta$ be the angle that the roof makes with the ground (floor). This is $\angle CAM$.

Note that 
$$\tan\theta=\frac{CM}{AM}=\frac{40}{15}.$$

Now use your calculator to find the angle whose tangent is $\frac{40}{15}$. This will involve using the $\tan^{-1}$ button.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

[image: hint]

$\theta$ is the angle you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a depiction of the A-frame house:

[image: The A-frame house]

Now it's just a matter of (a) finding $x$, and (b) using [SOHCAHTOA](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SOHCAHTOA.html) to find $\theta$.